# How do I get the Nth largest element from a list with duplicates, using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I've seen in various StackOverflow answers that I can get the Nth largest element in a list by doing something like

```
var nthFromTop = items.OrderByDescending().Skip(N-1).First();
```

But wouldn't this only work if there are no duplicates in the list? If the list contains duplicates, is there a way to get the Nth largest element (or set of elements) using LINQ? If not, what would be the most efficient way to do this in C#?

Comment: So if you have a set of `{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4}` and set `N` to `2` what do you expect the output to be?  Do you want to get distinct values then get the Nth largest?  Do you want to get the set of all elements equal to the Nth largest?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - ideally I'd like the set of all elements equal to the Nth largest

Comment: Then all of the posted answers are wrong.

Comment: If I obtain the Nth largest element, then I could write another query to get all the elements equal to that one. Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, there is.  I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the set of all items equal to the Nth largest item you'll need to group the items, order the groups, and then decrement N by the group size while N is positive.  When N reaches zero, you've hit the group containing the Nth largest item.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Foo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
{
    return source.GroupBy(x => x)
        .OrderByDescending(group => group.Key)
        .SkipWhile(group =>
        {
            n -= group.Count();
            return n > 0;
        })
        .First();
}
```

Comment: ahhhh so you noticed the exception....:)thats what i mean in my comment in my answer about you putting in yours...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get a set of all the elements, use GroupBy

```
 var items = new[] {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4};
 var thirdLargest = items
   .GroupBy(x => x)
   .OrderByDescending(group => group.Key)
   .ElementAt(2);
```

Comment: According to [the OP's clarification of what he is asking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455950/how-do-i-get-the-nth-largest-element-from-a-list-with-duplicates-using-linq?noredirect=1#comment37846813_24455950) your code does not produce the correct output.

Comment: @Servy I may be wrong, but how is ElementAt() method not returning a proper group? Ofc. beside the fact, that it should have parameter 1 instead of 2.

Comment: @Tarec If `N` is `2` it should return the set of items equal to the second largest item.  The second largest item in your sample input is `4`, so it should return the group of fours (the first group).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to avoid duplicates, how about using **group by**?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all values that are the Nth largest if there are duplicates do this:

EDIT

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>()
{
     1,2,5,8,12,34,12,52,34
};

int NthLargest = 1;
var queryresult = ints
                   .GroupBy(e => e)
                   .OrderByDescending(f => f.Count())
                   .ThenByDescending(k => k.Key)
                   .ElementAt(NthLargest - 1);
```

Comment: According to [the OP's clarification of what he is asking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455950/how-do-i-get-the-nth-largest-element-from-a-list-with-duplicates-using-linq?noredirect=1#comment37846813_24455950) your code does not produce the correct output.

Comment: No, it does not do the same thing at all.  Just try executing it on some of the example data sets used here to see for yourself.

Comment: i got it now,just realized what op wanted,then in my code(yes,yes i know it doesent matter now) its just placing in the orderbydescending f.Count() instead of f.Key.And your sure that in your code in the orderbydescending you dont wanna put that in?

Comment: Your code is still wrong, and I'm quite sure that my code is what I want it to be.  He doesn't want the group with the Nth largest size.  He wants to find the Nth largest item in the sequence, with duplicates and all, and then find the set of all items equal to that one item.  My solution is simply performing a functionally equivalent operation in a single pass.

Comment: no its not your assuming instead of trying op wants for example this sequence{1,2,2,2,2,3,12,12,34,34,34},the 2º nth largest would be the sequence{34,34,34},if this is not then the previous code was right which would have picked {12,12}.

Comment: In the example set you just gave, the 2nd largest item in the set is 34.  There is one item larger than it, and that item is `34`.  The set of items equal to `34` is `{34, 34, 34}`, so that is what the output should be.  So, yes, the output of that set where N is 2 is indeed `{34,34.34}`, but not because `{34,34,34}` is the second largest set.  That's just a coincidence.  To give a better example, given the set `{1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,5}` where N is 3 would return `{4}`, because `4` is the third largest item, and `{4}` is the set of all items equal to `4`.

Comment: if your last two items where 4 i would completly get it,its just applying an ThenByDescending(f => f.Key).

Comment: But they're not 4, they're 5, which means that the algorithm that you're using *doesn't* produce the correct output.  I choose that example precisely to show you that your algorithm doesn't work.  Ordering by the size of the group isn't correct, because there is nothing int he requirements about getting the Nth largest group.  Nothing at all.  It's about getting the group of items equal to the Nth largest individual item.  Your code doesn't do that, nor does your original revision.  Mine does.

Comment: No, three is not the 3rd largest item in the sequence.  There are two items larger than 4, those items are 5, and 5.  3 is the 3rd largest *distinct* item (which is not what he wants, and why every answer other than mine is wrong), not the 3rd largest item.  4 is the 3rd largest item.

Comment: ok finally i got it right in my head what op wants,jesus...thank you,then op really expressed himself very poorly

Comment: He expressed it poorly in the question , which was entirely ambiguous.  (Which is why I asked him to clarify it, instead of posting a guess of an answer, like the 4 people who got it wrong did.)  His comment, which I linked to you, was **very** clear.